# Customizing Lightning Navigation Bar

Tags: lightning-apps

I am new in Lightning. I have enabled the lightning for my org. I want to add some custom tabs which I have created in Classic view. How should I populate them in Lightning?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is available in Spring '16 under setup -> Navigation Menu.

Check this video

[**Customizing the Navigation Menu in Salesforce Lightning Experience**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m03kB3lYL7k)

> [image]

check this [Customize Tabs on Lightning Experience Record Pages Using the Lightning App Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=lightning_app_builder_customize_lex_pages_add_tabs.htm&language=en_US)